# Data driven subscription in SSRS 2005 showing error but not in log

Tags: reporting-services, logging

I'm troubleshooting a data driven subscription problem for a client.
We're trying to send to about 300 people- when we send to 50 people it works fine, but when we ramp up to 100 there are errors shown in report manager. 
For example: "Done: 100 processed of 100 total; 2 errors."

The problem is, these errors are not shown in the log file, so I can't troubleshoot the issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server 2005 logs are (default) located in this directory:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.3\Reporting Services\LogFiles
```

To select what should be written in the log follow this link on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157403(v=sql.90).aspx

Take a look to this post for some problems related to SSRS when sending reports via mail: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/cdcd6d2f-0136-405c-88ff-898ce0f6ac6e

Comment: Yes that's right. As mentioned in the question 'these errors are not shown in the log file'.

Comment: More helpful- thanks! I'd still like to know how to find out what the error is so not marked as answer, but +1ed.